# How to use HttpResponseRedirect with indicating class name?

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I have model named Tour. This model has classes `Inbound`, `Outbound`, `Education`.
For each of tour types I made custom page in admin panel. For this purpose I override urls and created views in admin.py file. Each view has formset.
So when I submit formset, browser shows me POST message. To solve this issue I use `HttpResponseRedirect` with `reverse()`.

And my problem is that when I submit formset of `Outbound` or `Education` classes, my view returns the view of `Inbound` class. I think it's due to the fact that view in each class have same name. I tried to rename them to be unique (like `def five_destinations_inbound` etc.), but it didn't help.

So my question is how to indicate class name in `HttpResponseRedirect`? Or is there another solution?
My admin.py code:

```python
class InboundAdmin(TranslationAdmin, ListView):
    model = Inbound

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(InboundAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
                           url(r'^five_destinations/$',
                               self.admin_site.admin_view(self.five_destinations),
                               name='five_destinations')
                           )
        return my_urls + urls

    def five_destinations(self, request, template='admin/tour/inbound/five_destination.html'):
        five_destination_formset = modelformset_factory(FiveDestinationsInbound, form=FiveDestinationInboundForm,
                                                        extra=3, max_num=3)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            formset = five_destination_formset(request.POST, request.FILES)
            formset.save(commit=False)
            if formset.is_valid():
                # some code, some logic
                formset.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:five_destinations'))
        else:
            formset = five_destination_formset()
        return render(request, template, locals())


class OutboundAdmin(TranslationAdmin):
    model = Outbound

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(OutboundAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
                           url(r'^five_destinations/$',
                               self.admin_site.admin_view(self.five_destinations),
                               name='five_destinations')
                           )
        return my_urls + urls

    def five_destinations(self, request, template='admin/tour/outbound/five_destination.html'):
        five_destination_formset = modelformset_factory(FiveDestinationsOutbound, form=FiveDestinationOutboundForm,
                                                        extra=3, max_num=3)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            formset = five_destination_formset(request.POST, request.FILES)
            formset.save(commit=False)
            if formset.is_valid():
                # some code, some logic
                formset.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:five_destinations'))
        else:
            formset = five_destination_formset()
        return render(request, template, locals())


class EducationAdmin(TranslationAdmin):
    model = Education

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(EducationAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
                           url(r'^five_destinations/$',
                               self.admin_site.admin_view(self.five_destinations),
                               name='five_destinations')
                           )
        return my_urls + urls

    def five_destinations(self, request, template='admin/tour/outbound/five_destination.html'):
        five_destination_formset = modelformset_factory(FiveDestinationsEducation, form=FiveDestinationEducationForm,
                                                        extra=3, max_num=3)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            formset = five_destination_formset(request.POST, request.FILES)
            formset.save(commit=False)
            if formset.is_valid():
                # some code, some logic
                formset.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:five_destinations'))
        else:
            formset = five_destination_formset()
        return render(request, template, locals())
```

Comment: You should rename one (or both) of the url names in `urls.py`.

Comment: I have nothing in urls.py related with this problem. This is admin.py file, where I set urls in `get_urls` method in each class. When I was trying to rename method `five_destinations` in each class I have made changes on `get_urls`, but it didn't help.